# Oracle SQL or PLSQL scale with load

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Suppose I have query ( it has joins on multiple tables ) and assuming it is tuned, and optimized. This query runs on the target database/tables with N number of records and query results R number of records and takes time T. Now gradually the load increases and say the target records become N2, and result it give is R2 and time it takes as T2. Assuming that I have allocated enough memory to the Oracle, L2/L1 will be close to T2/T1. Means the proportional increase in the load will result proportional increase in execution time. For this question lets say L2 = 5L1, means load has increased to 5times. Then time take to complete by this query would also be 5times or little more, right? So, to reduce the proportional growth in time, do we have options in Oracle, like parallel hint etc? In Java we split the job in multiple threads and 2times the load with 2times the worker thread we get almost same time to complete. So with increasing load we increase the worker thread and achieve the scaling issue reasonably well. Is such thing possible in Oracle or does Oracle take care of such thing in the back end and will scale, by splitting the load internally into parallel processing? Here, I have multi core processors. I Will experiment it, but if expert opinion is available it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Query algorithms do not necessarily grow linearly.

You should probably learn something about algorithms and complexity.  But many algorithms used in a data are super-linear.  For instance, ordering a set of rows has a complexity of O(n log n), meaning that if you double the data size, the time taken for sorting *more than doubles*.

This is also true of index lookups and various join algorithms.

On the other hand, if your query is looking up a few rows using a b-tree index, then the complex is O(log n) -- this is sublinear.  So index lookups grow more slowly than the size of the data.

So, in general you cannot assume that increasing the size of data by a factor of `n` has a linear effect on the time.

Comment: It answered the question, but have one follow up discussion point. A query can have order by and as it will be O(n log n), then this query will perform slower than O(n) proportional growth. In such case do we have any option to scale it better?

Comment: @user3072859 . . . Sometimes an index can help with ordering, but it depends on the query and the keys.